# What is Xdata protocol?

Tags: javascript

I need to understand what Xdata protocol is. I searched on internet but I can't find anything helps. We are a REU team trying to add a sensor on a interface that only take sensors with Xdata protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same information, this is the best document I could find:
ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/user/jordan/iMet-1-RSB%20Radiosonde%20XDATA%20Daisy%20Chaining.pdf

Basically, an XDATA packet is ASCII-formated, and looks like this:
xdata=01010123456789abcdef

Where:
"xdata=" - header
"01" - instrument ID
"01" - instrument position in daisy chain (more than one instrument can be connected)
the rest is data

Another document mentions that packet should be terminated with CR/LF: ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/user/jordan/XDATA%20Packet%20Example.pdf

Please note that XDATA doesn't seem to specify the data structure. It appears that the data processing is up to the ground station.

Since you didn't specify the radiosonde and instrument you plan to use, I won't write too much here, but you can go to http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/ozwv/wvap/sw.html where there is a little bit more information about the protocol (but not too much).

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of the docs and website linked in the previous answer.  Blagus summarized it well.  Any instrument you want to send data through an xdata-compatible radiosonde (typically the iMet-1-RSB) to the ground should output 3.3V (3V works too) UART serial packets at 9600 baud (8-N-1, typically no flow control) according to the protocol.  We keep track of a [list of instrument ID numbers](ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/user/jordan/XDATA%20Instrument%20ID%20Allocation.pdf) here to avoid conflicts, feel free to contact us to add a new instrument in the future (while prototyping, you can just make one up).

You can also "daisy chain" several xdata instruments together.  Any incoming xdata packets have their DC index incremented and then are forwarded down the chain.  When xdata packets reach the radiosonde they are stripped of their header info, a CRC is calculated and appended, then they are transmitted as binary FSK radio data to the antenna on the ground.  The antenna/preamp is connected to a receiver and then SkySonde Server/Client can decode the data (if using an iMet radiosonde) from the receiver's audio output.

Comment: Hi, do you maintain any lists or information regarding the packet design for these various instruments. I'm working on decoders with OIF411 and CFH both partially implemented.

Comment: The OIF411 (made by Vaisala) and CFH (made by Holger Vomel) are both closed protocol instruments, I don't have any information on how to decode them unfortunately.  You could try contacting Frank Wienhold at ETH Zurich, as he's written a CFH plugin for SkySonde:

https://usys.ethz.ch/en/people/profile.MTExMzY5.TGlzdC82MzcsMzIwMTk3MjIy.html

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, we have JavaScript decoders working for those and COBALD but are trying to find information about other XDATA instruments. https://github.com/projecthorus/sondehub-tracker/blob/testing/js/xdata.js

Comment: In particular, the FPH flown by NOAA would be good if you had any info on the transmitted data format: https://gml.noaa.gov/ozwv/wvap/instrument.html

Comment: The FPH protocol is on our website, open this document and look at the "Hygrometer XDATA Packet" section:

https://gml.noaa.gov/aftp/user/jordan/iMet%20Radiosonde%20Protocol.pdf